# How to Run Powershell commands Sequentially

Tags: powershell

I have some commands which can only be ran when prefixed with `&`.

They all run asynchronously.

Example script:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\SomeApp\SomeAppUninstall.exe'/silent
& 'C:\Users\bob\Downloads\SomeApp.exe' /silent
& 'C:\Program Files\someApp.exe' /openGui
```

What happens here is the last command will happen first as it is the fastest and the program is still installed, the first 2 will run simultaneously leading to a conflict.

I need the them run sequentially obviously.

For some reason these commands only work if prefixed with `&` or I get an error, I suspect it's because they have switches.

How do I get around this?

Comment: _Leading_ & in powershell does not run something in 'background'; instead it can run something that PS doesn't normally consider a command, including a string literal value as in your case. PS _does_ run 'in background' (concurrently) any windows-mode executable _program_ -- i.e. one that puts up its own display window rather than doing output to (and if applicable input from) the PS console. To run such a program and wait for it, instead use [Start-Process with the -wait option](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html) -- see the next to last paragraph before the heading Examples.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for pointing to documentation, perhaps you weren't confident and deferred to a more credible source, which is a good call instead of making a blunder or perhaps you were occupied and couldn't put in the effort, very understandable, I thank you profusely, however I worked it out by myself as your link was dead the last time I clicked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example I gave was very simple, actual cases are a bit more complex, but my cases all only use 1 argument.

I wrote this simple function:

```
function Await($path, $arg) {
    Start-Process     `
      -Wait           `      
      -FilePath $path `
      -ArgumentList /$arg 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago, I have written a Powershell function because I had the same or at least a similar requirement as you.
If I recall correctly, this function served me well - altough I believe I once encountered a hiccup which I couldn't explain.
Thus, use at your own risk.

```
function wait-for-process {
   param (
     [string] $exe,
     [string] $arguments
   )

  $process                     = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
  $process.StartInfo           = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
  $process.StartInfo.FileName  = $exe
  $process.StartInfo.Arguments = $arguments

  if (-not $process.Start()) {
    "Could not start $exe $arguments!"
     return
  }
  $process.WaitForExit()
  
  if ($process.ExitCode) {
    "Exit code for $exe $arguments is $($process.ExitCode)"
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've hardly used Powershell, so can't understand all of that but I appreciate it, thanks. I am usually scripting on linux, and had to use Powershell for windows stuff. I know I don't have any error handling but my cases are quite simple and I'll likely not have to use Powershell much again. I just wrote came up with that function a couple of hours ago.